# Lubuntu ask-trash-empty doesn't work

Tags: lubuntu, trash

I'm using Lubuntu 16.04. After following [these](http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/323-lubuntu-trusty-empty-trash-menu) instructions, my empty trash button appears on the trash menu ---- but it doesn't work.

I've tried to run the ask-trash-empty file on its own and it doesn't work either.
I've checked and everything is on the right place.

Can somebody help? Thank you in advance!

Comment: The instruction there works just file in 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have found a solution.
I had the same problem with my Lubuntu 16.04 32bit, and I solved it by installing the `zenity` package.

Hope this helps

MsieurLOU